# Compilation failure Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>data-access-framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>data-access-framework</artifactId>
                <version>${version.snapshot}</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>2402: data-access-framework</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

         <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java-version}</source>
                        <target>${java-version}</target>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.10</version>
                  <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/reports</reportsDirectory>
                  </configuration>
             </plugin> 
        </plugins>
      </build>  


      <parent>
            <groupId>data-access-layer</groupId>
            <artifactId>data-access-layer</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>



        <dependencies> 

         <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
             <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 


        </dependencies>



    </project>

when i am running mvn clean install command then it gives this error i have plugin its compiler and all and every thing but it still gives this error
```

All other dependencies are managed from its parent pom and parent pom doesnt give any error but it giving this error.
in its parent pom i have added the same plugin as in it
please give me some suggestion how to resolve this problem and i have set all environment variable and i have other p[oms also but only this pom giving the error

Comment: any body know this problem

Comment: Please post the error. Maybe the colon in the name "2402: ..." makes a problem. Put this into a description tag instead